# How to check if a parameter is null or has a value in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I want to run code based on whether the parameter value exists or not.

**For example:**

If I hit this url

```
http://localhost/myproject/index.php/1
```

code works perfectly as it has a parameter value

But if I hit this url

```
http://localhost/myproject/index.php/
```

**I get error of too few arguments to the function in index()**

**Here is my index function in the controller:**

```
public function index($id)
{
    if(isset($id))
    {
        //do some code
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `public function index($id = '')`

```
public function index($id = '')
{
    if(!empty($id)){
        //Coding...
    }
    else{
        return $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: error is gone but if their is no value then the else condition is not working

Comment: try this `if(!empty($id))`

Comment: @DanishAli what if we write only one `if(!empty($id)){`?

Comment: obviously a typo, fixed it for him

Comment: oh! I didn't see it. Thanks @Alex